Как установить пакет virtualbox-7.0? VB-linux-ubuntu
Я следовал инструкциям на сайте VirtualBox:

Создал файл /etc/apt/sources.d/vb.list (вместо редактирования существующего /etc/apt/sources.list) и записал в него: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib

В консоли прописал команду: wget -O- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo gpg --yes --output /usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg --dearmor

Выполнил: sudo apt update (В списках появились нужные пакеты)

Выполнил: sudo apt instal virtualbox-7.0


Получил вывод:
    Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
    Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
    Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
    Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
    неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
    запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
    Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

    Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
     virtualbox-7.0 : Зависит: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) но он не может быть установлен
                      Рекомендует: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 но он не будет установлен
    E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.


Пробовал:

Исправить поломанные пакеты через sudo apt -f install

Найти и установить этот пакет libvpx7 (Конкретно такого пакета не нашел, только libvpx9, и то он уже был установлен...)

В ручную установил libsdl-ttf2.0-0

Установить virtualbox-6.0 (Вывод аналогичен)


Ничего не помогло
Кто знает что я делаю не так?
Даже файла с этим пакетом (libvpx7) в интернете не нашел, может хотя бы ссылку кто кинет.

«что я делаю не так?» — используете репозиторий от не той версии убунты, например?

@andreymal Вы полностью правы. По курсу препод использовал версию 24.04, но во всех примерах показывал jammy... За то теперь буду бдительнее)

Если юзаешь ansible - можешь попробовать https://github.com/don-rumata/ansible-role-install-virtualbox . Ставил на 24.04 - всё поехало ок.

Использовал неверную версию пакета deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib
Вместо версии для noble (24.04), использовал jammy (22.04)
PS: Спасибо andreymal за помощь!
